# SQL queries producing unexpected results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got a strange situation with two SQL queries that aren't producing the expected results. Here are the queries:

Query 1:

`SELECT DISTINCT SomeCharValue
 FROM Table1
 JOIN Table2
 ON Table1.SomeCharValue = Table2.SomeCharValue
 ORDER BY SomeCharValue`

Query 2:

`SELECT DISTINCT SomeCharValue
 FROM Table1
 JOIN Table2
 ON Table1.SomeCharValue <> Table2.SomeCharValue
 ORDER BY SomeCharValue`

I have two tables with columns of varchar(15). Table2 is essentially a small subset of the values in Table1, thus Table1 has all values stored in Table2. The problem is, the two queries should never produce the same results, yet they do. Both queries will produce the same result for certain values; for example, if Table1 and Table2 contain the word 'hello', then Query 1 should return it, while Query 2 should not. However, BOTH queries return 'hello'. It doesn't make sense that 'hello' in both tables is equal and not equal at the same time. I ran a length query to test the values, and some were a different size with trailing white spaces, but even after changing these to be an exact match, and verifying the hexadecimal value of the characters to be the same, the same results occur. I can't compare numeric key fields since there is no key relationship between these tables. I can only compare the exact character values in the columns. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you have table1 containing `a` and `b` as separate rows, and table2 has the exact same contents.

Now for your second query, table1's row `a` will be compared to both the rows in table2. It will pass the ON clause when comparing to row `b` in table2, and hence `a` will be in your result set. Similarly for the `b` row in table1 which will pass the ON clause when compared to the `a` row in table2.

You could rewrite the query as

`SELECT DISTINCT SomeCharValue
FROM TABLE1
WHERE SomeCharValue NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT SomeCharValue FROM Table2)
ORDER BY SomeCharValue`

Comment: I just stumbled onto using a nested select statement right before checking this answer. This is absolutely the correct approach to solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use NOT LIKE instead of <>